# Renaming a file with Amazon S3 PHP SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, rename

I’m struggling to rename a file within the same bucket with Amazon S3 SDK. I am referring to [copy object](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_copyObject) in the API docs.

Here is my call, but it keeps returning “specified bucket does not exist”.

```
$clients = S3Client::factory(array(
        'key'    => 'key',
        'secret' => 'secret'
    ));

    try {

        $result = $clients->copyObject(array(
                'ACL' => 'private',
                // Bucket is required
                'Bucket' => 'david1982.audio',
                // CopySource is required
                'CopySource' =>  'mp3/music.mp3',
                // Key is required
                'Key' => 'mp3/music_name_updated.mp3',
                'MetadataDirective' => 'REPLACE'
        ));

    echo json_encode($result);

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo json_encode($e->getMessage());
}
```

Before someone points out the obvious and asks “Does your bucket exist?’ yes, it definitely exists. I can run a call with the same keys and get all my files from that bucket.

I really want to be able to rename a file via the API. You can do it within the Amazon S3 Browser.

---

### Solution found

For some reason, you have to include the bucket in `CopySource`.

```
$result = $clients->copyObject(array(
                'ACL' => 'private',
                // Bucket is required
                'Bucket' => 'david1982.audio',
                // CopySource is required
                'CopySource' =>  'david1982.audio/mp3/music.mp3',
                // Key is required
                'Key' => 'mp3/music_name_updated.mp3',
                'MetadataDirective' => 'REPLACE'
        ));
```

Comment: Could you post the exact wording of the error message?

Comment: The specified bucket does not exist

Comment: Have you tried specifying region in the client factory?

Comment: Hi Antony thanks for your help but its not that i can copy a file to a different bucket but not the same one to rename.

Comment: Looking around, this kind of problem can be caused by the naming rules of the bucket. But the name looks right in your example.

Comment: Hi Antony i have managed to fix it i will update the question i wish they would make this clear in the documentation

Comment: Good fix. You know it would be good for you to answer your own question and accept your own answer so that future readers can find it easierly.

Comment: It says right in the documentation "CopySource - The name of the source bucket and key name of the source object, separated by a slash (/). Must be URL-encoded."

Answer (score 19):

If anybody ends up here looking for the best way of how to do this nowadays in PHP, you can rename s3 files like this:

```
$s3sdk = new Sdk($awsConfig);
$s3 = $s3sdk->createS3();
$s3->registerStreamWrapper();
rename($oldName, $newName);
```

both names need to contain the full s3 path e.g:

```
"s3://yourBucketName/path/to/file"
```

Basically `registerStreamWrapper()` enables PHP filesystem commands for s3 files.

Comment: When using `rename` can you specify the ACL of the target file? Which ACL does it get by default? (e.g. that of the original file or always "private" or ?)

Comment: is it possible to rename a file on your local server using the path from the s3? like `rename('workspace/folder/test.txt', 's3://yourBucketName/folder/test1.txt')`

Answer (score 12):

Yes, to copy an object you have to specify the bucket name of the object to copy.

Below an example from the official documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjectUsingPHP.html)

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

$sourceBucket = '*** Your Source Bucket Name ***';
$sourceKeyname = '*** Your Source Object Key ***';
$targetBucket = '*** Your Target Bucket Name ***';
$targetKeyname = '*** Your Target Key Name ***';        

// Instantiate the client.
$s3 = S3Client::factory();

// Copy an object.
$s3->copyObject(array(
    'Bucket'     => $targetBucket,
    'Key'        => $targetKeyname,
    'CopySource' => "{$sourceBucket}/{$sourceKeyname}",
));
```

After you copied the object, you'll have to delete the old one, here's an example:

```
$result = $client->deleteObject(array(
    'Bucket' => 'string',
    'Key' => 'string'
));
```

Comment: There is a problem though, once the file names are the same, in this case `targetKeyname` and `sourceKeyname`, it ends up deleting the file.

Comment: @penguin compare target and source names before rename. If they match, reject that operation e.g. by throwing exception.